# Question about " protest-hit"

Tags: word-meaning, headlinese

Taiwan leader says protest-hit China trade pact vital for economy.

My perception : protest -hit is an adjective meaning be attacked by protest.

Answer (score 2):

Your conjecture is correct: *protest-hit* means *subjected to protest*.  The entire headline may be paraphrased:

> The President of Taiwan has said that the proposed trade agreement with China, which has recently been the object of vigorous protest, is vital to Taiwan’s economy.

Headline English crunches syntax, often grotesquely, in order to produce shorter strings of words. It should not be taken as a model in your own writing.

Comment: This agrees with what I have read on Internet in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

It just mean that Chinese trade is under the affects of ongoing protest. Or you can say that Chinese trade which has influenced by protest is vital for economy.